# Why I get YouTube The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions?

Tags: python

I don't really understand The youtube data API v3 when I tested the code at some channels to get the subscribers list it works but at other channels not working and getting this issue

"youtube The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions reason subscriptions Forbidden"

and that is my code with python and I will attach a screenshot for the channel id subscribers list

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


name="UCnicwoLw74ntPebaDW68AEg"

key="APIKey"


youtube = build('youtube','v3',developerKey=key)

def get_channel_status(youtube, channel_id):
    request = youtube.subscriptions().list(
        part="Snippet",
        channelId=channel_id,
        maxResults=1000
    )
    response = request.execute()
    
    return response['items']



channel_status = get_channel_status(youtube,name)
```

and the 2nd thing is why I got only 23 one while he has more than 2k subscribers? [Channel Subscribers List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp5T7.png)

Comment: maybe some channels don't allow for subscription - and this is not problem with code

Comment: API may send data in pagination . OR maybe some values are for persons which paid for access to all data.

Comment: @furas the bad thing I'm trying to get my own channel subscribers list but not working :(

Comment: you could add link to this channel so we could see it directly in browser.

Comment: @furas well that's my channel link https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkPnwNsMJnZ1QbaZSgSqKBg